# Congruency proving an integer solution is not possible, Gauss

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In Gauss' *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, at the end of Section I he writes that $x^2-8x+6 \: modulo \: 5$ yields the periodic residuals ${1,4,3,4}$, thus   $x^2-8x+6 \ncong 0 \: or \: 2 \: modulo \: 5$, hence $x^2-8x+6 \neq 0$ for any integer $x$. In other words there are no integer solutions to that equation (or to $x^2-8x+4$).

I do not understand the reasoning. Why would the lack of a solution modulo 5, imply lack of a solution at all?

Comment: $$   0 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 $$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there exists a solution $a$ in integers $x\in \Bbb Z$ such that $x^2-8x+6=0$, hence we have $a^2-8a+6=0$, this equation would also be true modulo any integer so it's true modulo $5$ then:
$$a^2+8a+6 \equiv 0\mod 5 $$

so $a\mod 5$ is a solution of $x^2-8x+6=0$ in $\Bbb Z_5$ which is impossible because there is no solution to this equation in $\Bbb Z_5$.

So our assumption is falso and there is no solution for $x^5-8x+6$ in the set of integers. this can be generalized to any polynomial $P$